# Retrieving API version programmatically using Context

Tags: android

I'm currently developing an Android library. In a Class of that library I need to check the Android OS version and do different things depending on the Android OS version.

My problem is that I know I'm supposed to use `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`, but I don't know how to use it outside an activity.

I have a class like the following:

```
public class VersionService {

    Context contextProvider;

    public VersionService(Context contextProvider) {
        this.contextProvider = contextProvider;
    }

    public boolean versionChanged(String profileId) {
        try {
            String versionCode = String.valueOf(
                    contextProvider.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName()
                            , 0).versionCode);
            String osCode = //Here I have to find the OS version using context,
                             similar to how I got versionCode

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return appUpdated;
    }
}
```

How can I get the OS version using context?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you can literally just put `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` anywhere you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Build.VERSION.RELEASE` to get Android version as displayed in About Phone information